# Priority queue in c++ stl

Tags: c++, stl, containers, priority-queue

I want to design a priority queue which in the priority of element with lower value of t[] is highest. This thing i am able to achieve.

But i also want that elements whose s[] value is zero should be at the end (regardless of their t [] value)
How can i modify my code for that?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long

ll t[4];
ll s[4];

struct func
{
  bool operator()(const ll lhs, const ll rhs) const
  {
    return(t[lhs] > t[rhs]);
  }
};

int main(){
t[0]=2;t[1]=3;t[2]=0;t[3]=6;
s[0]=0;s[1]=0;s[2]=1;s[3]=1;
priority_queue<ll,vector<ll>,func>pq;

pq.push(0);
pq.push(1);
pq.push(2);
pq.push(3);

// for displaying

cout<<pq.top()<<endl;
pq.pop();

cout<<pq.top()<<endl;
pq.pop();

cout<<pq.top()<<endl;
pq.pop();

cout<<pq.top()<<endl;
pq.pop();
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you learn to include `bits/stdc++.h`? It isn't a standard header, making your code non-portable.

Comment: `#define ll long long`  I really don't understand the purpose of macros like this.  We all know what `long long` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check both: if one of `s`s is zero, return that as lower priority, otherwise compare `t`s:

```cpp
bool operator() (const ll lhs, const ll rhs) const {
  const bool leftIsZero = s[lhs] == 0;
  const bool rightIsZero = s[rhs] == 0;
  const bool oneIsZero = leftIsZero ^ rightIsZero;

  if (oneIsZero)
    return rightIsZero;

  return t[lhs] > t[rhs];
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't, it compares `t`s in that case.